# tcolorbox not centering in absolute positioning tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, tcolorbox, tikz-node

Alright people, I've stumped myself again. It appears (to me at least) that tcolorbox has some outside margins or padding that I don't know how to control.

I use tikz absolute positioning to format the elements of my letters that I need in specific space. For example, this below payment slip need to stay inside the top third of this page (represented by the red filling) because this will be printed on a perforated page.

[image: north east 0,0 offset]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{letter}
\usepackage[lmargin=30pt,rmargin=30pt,tmargin=30pt,bmargin=30pt,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning} 
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\graphicspath{{/usr/local/lariat/.template/lib/img/logo/}}




 \pgfdeclarelayer{back}
 \pgfdeclarelayer{front}
 \pgfsetlayers{back,main,front}

\begin{document}

\fontencoding{T1}
\fontfamily{phv}
\fontsize{10}{12}
\selectfont



\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

    \begin{pgfonlayer}{front}




        \node [xshift=-0pt,yshift=0pt, fill=red, minimum height=264pt, minimum width=614pt,anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {};

        \node [xshift=-0pt,yshift=-5pt, anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {
            \begin{tcolorbox}[width=582pt, colframe=darkgray, colback=darkgray, left=-3pt, top=-5pt, coltitle=white, boxsep=2mm, boxcolor=red,boxrule=.1mm, arc=1.5mm, title=\centering \textbf{Payment Authorization}]
                \includegraphics[width=575pt]{paymentform.pdf} 
            \end{tcolorbox}
        };


    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Additionally, I've noticed that my letter paper is actually 614pt instead of 612pt wide, does anyone know why that is?

Thanks in advance for your assistance you beautiful Latex people.

Comment: I can not compile your code. It is missing some pdf.

Comment: If you use `showframe` option in `geometry` you can have a better idea how the page contents are positioned.

Comment: Also, maybe you wish `lmargin=0pt,rmargin=0pt,paperwidth=614pt`.

Comment: Here is where my confusion comes in, my tcolorbox is in a tikz node that is absolute positioned to the page.north east. It isn't (or shouldn't be) affected by the page margins. 

The red node behind my tcolorbox does position to the north east exactly. It's just the tcolorbox that seems to have some kind of padding around it.

Comment: `boxcolor` is no valid `tcolorbox` key -- your whole example is not compilable, misses the important `.pdf` file and has packages you don't need in order to show the issue...

Comment: Have you tried to replace `\node [xshift=-0pt,yshift=-5pt, anchor=north east] at (current page.north east)  ... ` by `\node [anchor=north east] at ([xshift=-0pt,yshift=-5pt]current page.north east)  ...` ?

Comment: `TikZ` nodes have some `inner sep` which makes that the inner tcolorbox is not adjusted with node's corner. By the way, if you only use `tcolorbox` to include an image, why not use a `tikz` node?

Comment: In support of @Ignasi, I would also just include the graphics clipped against a box with rounded corners. (I never really understood how adding a `tcolorbox` in a node of a `tikzpicture` is not subject to the same concerns we have against nesting `tikzpicture`s. True, `tcolorbox` uses `pgf` commands, but they are subject to pgfkeys as well. I would not be surprised if you are seeing these effects here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an alternative construction without `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{letter}
\usepackage[lmargin=30pt,rmargin=30pt,tmargin=30pt,bmargin=30pt,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[fill=red, 
        minimum height=264pt, minimum width=614pt, 
      below left=0pt of current page.north east] (A) {};

\matrix[rounded corners, fill=darkgray,     
    below left=0pt of current page.north east] 
    {
        \node[anchor=center, font=\sffamily\bfseries, color=white]{Payment Authorization};\\
        \node[anchor=center, inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=575pt, height=200pt]{example-image-A}};\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Ignasi! I suppose I was using tcolorbox because it makes for some quick and easy formatting across my applications, especially when I'm using different color headers, borders, and body. I suppose I'll need to up by node formatting game.